# Monte Carlo simulation Python

Tags: python-2.7

Question:
 You have a bucket with 3 red balls and 3 green balls.
 Assume that once you draw a ball out of the bucket, you don't replace it. 
 What is the probability of drawing 3 balls of the same color?

Problem: My code always gives 0.0

```
import random
def noReplacementSimulation(numTrials):
    '''
    Runs numTrials trials of a Monte Carlo simulation
    of drawing 3 balls out of a bucket containing
    3 red and 3 green balls. Balls are not replaced once
    drawn. Returns the a decimal - the fraction of times 3 
    balls of the same color were drawn.
    '''

    for i in range(numTrials):
        hola=0
        b=['r','r','r','g','g','g']
        for a in range(3):
          ball=random.choice(b)
          b.remove(ball)
        if b[0]==b[1] and b[1]==b[2] and b[2]==b[0]:
            hola=hola+1
    return float(hola)/numTrials
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code *doesn't* always return `0.0`, only most of the time.  You reset

```
hola=0
```

*inside the loop*, so you can only end with either `hola == 0` or `hola == 1`.  You want

```
hola=0
for i in range(numTrials):
    # stuff here
```

instead.

PS: the question asks "What is the probability of drawing 3 balls of the same color?" but you're checking whether the three balls which are *left* are of the same colour.  Those won't be the same in general.

Comment: Another small problem (this is more nitpicking) is that his code only checks what's left in the bucket for everything being the same (which in this case works because there are only two sets).  But if the bucket ever had `b=['r','r','r','g','g','g', 'b', 'b', 'b']` for example you would not be finding the probability of drawing three balls of the same color